# How to rename a VIEW in Sybase IQ

Tags: database, sap-iq

I'm using IQ version 15.4.

sp_iqrename works for all object types except views.
ALTER VIEW RENAME statement also doesn't work.

Is renaming views allowed in IQ? How to do this ?